# Can't understand step in LU decomposition proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**UPDATE**: The author of the linked article has updated the proof and now it's perfectly clear.

I'm reading about the LU decomposition on [this page](https://statlect.com/matrix-algebra/lu-decomposition) and cannot understand one of the final steps in the proof to the following:

> Let $A$ be a $K\times K$ matrix. Then, there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that $PA$ has an LU decomposition: $$PA=LU$$ where $L$ is a lower triangular $K\times K$ matrix and $U$ is an upper triangular $K\times K$ matrix.

I'll reproduce the proof here:

> Through Gaussian elimination, $A$ can be reduced to a row-echelon (hence upper triangular) matrix $U$ via a series of $n$ elementary operations: $$E_n\bullet\ldots\bullet E_1\bullet A = U$$
>   Any elementary matrix $E_i$ used in Gaussian elimination is either a permutation matrix $P_i$ or a matrix $L_i$ used to add a multiple of one row to a row **below** it. Thus, $L_i$ will be lower triangular with non-zero diagonal $\implies$ invertible. Suppose that the first permutation matrix we encounter is in position $j$, so that we have:
>   $$E_n\bullet\ldots\bullet E_{j+1}\bullet P_j\bullet L_{j-1}\bullet\ldots\bullet L_1\bullet A = U$$
>   Since a permutation matrix is orthogonal, $P_j^T P_j = I$ and hence
>   $$E_n\bullet\ldots\bullet E_{j+1}\bullet P_j\bullet L_{j-1}\bullet P_j^TP_j \bullet\ldots\bullet P_j^TP_j\bullet L_1\bullet P_j^TP_j\bullet A = U$$ or
>   $$E_n\bullet\ldots\bullet E_{j+1}\bullet\tilde{L}_{j-1}\bullet\ldots\bullet\tilde{L}_1\bullet P_j\bullet A = U$$
>   for $i=1,\ldots,j-1$. A matrix $L_i$, used to add $\alpha$ times the $i$-th row to the $s$-th row (in this case $s>i$), can be written as a rank one update to the identity matrix: $L_i=I+M$, where $M$ is a matrix whose entries are all zeros except $M_{si} = \alpha$. We have that
>   $$\tilde{L}_i = P_jL_iP_j^T = P_j(I+M)P_j^T = P_jP_j^T + P_jMP_j^T = I+P_jMP_j^T$$

So far so good. Then we have:

> **The permutations performed on the rows and columns of $M$ by $P_j$ and $P_j^T$ can move the only non-zero element of $M$, but that element remains below the main diagonal (because $j>i$).**

I can't understand this. $M$ is derived from $L_i$, which means that $M_{si} = \alpha \neq 0$ and all other elements of $M$ are $0$. Nothing has been said about $P_j$. I'm guessing $P_j$ swaps $j$-th row with $r$-th row, where $r>j$. What do the indices $s,i$ have anything to do with the indices $r,j$?

Would be grateful if anyone could clear this up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof states $P_j$ is a permutation matrix. There is no explicit restriction on what $P_j$ permutes, but there is an *implicit* one, which has to do with the order in which row reduction steps are done.

Since $j > i$, meaning that $P_j$ was performed **after** the lower triangulars $L_1, L_2, \ldots, L_{j-1}$, it must be the case that $P_j$ only permutes rows $j+1$ and greater (since rows 1 through $j$ are taken care of by the lower triangulars $L_1, L_2, \ldots, L_{j-1}$). So, if $P_j$ swaps the rows $q$ and $r$, we have $q,r > j \ge s > i$.

Basically, the implicit restriction on $P_j$ leaves $\tilde L_i = L_i$, since the elements of $P_j$ and $P_j^T$ are the same as $I$ for rows/columns $1$ through $j$.

FWIW - the fact that this detail was not mentioned in my opinion makes this proof fairly poorly constructed, and introducing all of the $\tilde L$ notation makes it difficult to parse. A much better proof approach would be to demonstrate that $L_i$ and $P_j$ commute.

---

**Example.** In this example, we will take

- $i = 1$ (column number of nonzero element of $M$)
- $s = 2$ (row number of nonzero element of $M$)
- $j = 2$ (row reduction step number of permutation $P$)
- $q = 3$ (one of two rows permuted by $P$)
- $r = 4$ (one of two rows permuted by $P$)

A possible choice of $L_1$ and $P_2$ are as follows.

$$L_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{1 in} P_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

From these, we can derive $M$ and $P^T$.

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{1 in} P_2^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, compute $\tilde L_1 = P_2 MP_2^T$ and notice that it equals $L_1$, and is thus lower diagonal.

$$\tilde L_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\tilde L_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = L_1$$

Comment: Just one small detail. Is it certain that $q$ and $r$ are both greater than $j$? I mean, it could mean that that $P_j$ exchanges the $j$-th row with the $r$-th row, where $r > j$. But even then, the non-zero element of $M$ would stay in the lower triangle. Thanks so much!

Comment: You can always do row reduction into echelon form with $q,r>j$, yes. You don't have to, but you always can. This proof demonstrates that it's always possible to factor $PA$ into $LU$, so the fact that you can, even though not necessarily, do row reduction this way does not contradict the proof.